# Perl: how can I set the version of perl for .pl file in linux

Tags: linux, perl

I am working on client site and have no access to root, so I can't do anything to the exiting perl version(5.1) installed in `usr/bin`, but I need to install additional modules for perl, so I installed my own version(5.2) of perl in my own home directory, and did the path setting.

I did check below:

```
which perl
```

gives me the correct directory.

And

```
perl -v
```

gives me 5.2.

But when I run a `.pl` file, the printout says it runs on `perl 5.10` again.

I have to do perl `xxx.pl` to run it on `perl 5.2`, if I just do `./xxx.pl`, it just runs on `perl 5.10`,

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Also `use 5.020;` to force a runtime failure if the version of Perl is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The path to perl is specified in the shebang line of the script.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
```

Either change it there to point to the correct install, or use

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
```

which should pick up the first perl executable on $PATH.

Or, run it with the interpreter specified in the command line:

```
/path/to/perl /path/to/script.pl
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you might want to look at is [PerlBrew](http://perlbrew.pl). This is a system that allows you to install Perl on most Unix/Linux and Mac OS X systems without having to have root access.

Even better, you can switch between versions of Perl:

```
$ perlbrew use 5.20
$ perl -v
This is perl 5, version 18 (blah, blah, blah)

$ perlbrew use 5.18
$ perl -v
This is perl 5, version 18 (yadda, yadda, yadda)
```

Perlbrew stores each version of Perl under your `$HOME` directory, and you can use the [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) to specify a particular version of Perl you want to use.

I've symbolically linked the different versions of Perl under `$HOME/bin` so I can do just that.